# Remove newline characters from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, character, newline

I have the below list

```
list = ['\n                                A\n                            ', '\n                                B\n                            ', '\n                                C\n                            ', '\n                                D\n                            ']
```

Seems like list is center aligned and this list is the output of bs4 code I run. How can I remove all the newline characters from this list that the final output looks like

```
list = ['A','B','C','D']
```

Comment: Your original list is invalid syntax. You re-bound a built-in and didn't close `]`

Comment: @roganjosh It's fine as far as syntax.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash did you try running the first line? I can't even test and it's broken from sight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove leading and trailing whitespace from a string. To apply it to each item in the list you can use a list comprehension:

```
lst = [item.strip() for item in lst]
```

or the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
lst = list(map(str.strip, lst))
```

As a side note, don't name your variable `list` as it would shadow the built-in [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: Thanks a lot @EugeneYarmash. Amidst confusion imposed by BeautifulSoup, I totally forgot this simple method!